# Changing radiolist to dropdown

Tags: php, yii2, dropdown

I have stuck ;/ I have activeradiolist and works ok, but I need to create another list bud with dropdowns item's
my code with $model for activeradioList

```
    echo Html::activeradioList($add, 'type_contact',
    $items, ['item' => function ($index, $label, $name, $checked, $value) {
        $return = '<div style="max-height:178px!important;" class="radio col-xs-12 col-lg-6"><input type="radio" name="' . $name . '" value="' . $value . '" tabindex="3" id="' . $name . $index . '" ' . ($checked ? 'checked' : '') . '>';
        $return .= '<label style="padding-top:0!important" for="' . $name . $index . '">' . $label . '</label></div>';
        if ($checked && $index === 1) {
            $return .= '<script>$(document).ready(function(){$(\'#ref-form\').slideDown()});</script>';
        }

        return $return;
    }]
); ?>
```

Now i try to convert this to dropdownList like ->

```
        echo CHtml::dropDownList($add, 'type_contact',
    $items, ['item' => function ($index, $label, $name, $checked, $value) {
        $return = '<div style="max-height:178px!important;" class="radio col-xs-12 col-lg-6"><input type="radio" name="' . $name . '" value="' . $value . '" tabindex="3" id="' . $name . $index . '" ' . ($checked ? 'checked' : '') . '>';
        $return .= '<label style="padding-top:0!important" for="' . $name . $index . '">' . $label . '</label></div>';
        if ($checked && $index === 1) {
            $return .= '<script>$(document).ready(function(){$(\'#ref-form\').slideDown()});</script>';
        }

        return $return;
    }]
); ?>
```

and have htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Comment: It looks like you wrote `CHtml` but you tagged the question yii2, `CHtml` is not a yii2 class

Answer (score 0):

1) The CHtml is class from old Yii 1.x framework. Yii2 doesn't use the `C` prefix for its class names.

2) You are pairing the form field with your model instance so you should use the `activeDropDownList()` method instead of `dropDownList()`.

3) In your radio button options you have `item` callback that is used to generate the html code for radio button. The drop down list doesn't have anything like that so you should remove it from its options. You can completly omit the fourth parameter because the item callback is the only option there.

So the code for drop down list should look like this:

```php
echo Html::activeDropDownList($add, 'type_contact', $items);
```

Comment: ok, this work but I have in activeradioList script when checked && $index === 1 then JS load form with slidedown effect. How Can i check in dropdownlist which element user select and load script without submiting value to mysql

Comment: You can use `$('#dropdownlistid').val()` in JS to get the currently selected value, just replace `#dropdownlistid` with the id of your select. You can also use `$('#dropdownlistid').change(function() { ... })` event if you need to react when user changes the selected value.